# DateTime[] and Object[] Issues

Tags: c#, datetime, object, casting

I recently was working with some dynamic Search Expressions and ran into a bit of an issue when I was attempting to search for multiple Date/Times.

**My SearchExpression constructors resemble the following (*some omitted for brevity*):**

```
public SearchExpression(string propertyName, 
                        ComparisonOperator comparisonOperator, 
                        object value) {...}
```

**and**

```
public SearchExpression(string propertyName, 
                        ComparisonOperator comparisonOperator, 
                        object[] values, 
                        BooleanOperator innerBooleanOperator) {...}
```

Both of these work as they should when passed the following :

- Strings
- Numbers (or any numerical data)

However, when it comes to passing DateTime information, I began to encounter some problems.

I have all of my data seperated when it comes in based on the type (DateTime, Numerical or String) and check for validity, they are then stored into array to pass to the proper expressions, like so:

```
object[] stringParameters;
object[] numericalParameters;
DateTime[] dateParameters;
```

All of these work when I pass in any of the above, with the exception of an array of DateTime parameters.

**So my question, *which leaves me feeling a bit foolish*, is why can I pass a single DateTime value as an object, but am unable to pass an** `DateTime[]` **as an** `object[]` **.**

**Example:**

```
DateTime[] dateParameters;

//This works fine
new SearchExpression("DateTime", ComparisonOperator.Equals, dateParameters[0]);

//This fails to work
new SearchExpression("DateTime", ComparisonOperator.Equals, dateParameters,
                     BooleanOperator.Or);
```

Comment: Exactly how does it fail? Compile error? Run time exception? or unexpected behaviour? details on any errors would be helpful.

Comment: It was just an invalid arguments error - when attempting to pass in the DateTime[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *inherently* a problem of `Covariance` which <s>**arrays do not support**</s> **arrays do not support for value types**.

**Eric Lippert** has a very good post on that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

---

## Solution

Change method signature to `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: Thanks for the Article Aliostad! I had considered using IEnumerable originally, but I suppose I was feeling classic when choosing to use an array. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Hope it has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can I pass a single DateTime
>   value as an object?

There is an implicit boxing conversion available from `DateTime` (a value-type) to `object`.

> But am unable to pass an DateTime[] as
>   an object[]?

There is no implicit conversion available from a `DateTime[]` to `object[]`. Although arrays in C# [exhibit covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) in general (for example, there is an implicit conversion from `string[]` to `object[]`), this does *not* extend to arrays of value-types - covariant conversions are currently required to be identity-preserving conversions, with good reason.

Comment: Thanks Ani - I appreciate it (also thanks for the post on covariance!)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass/cast DateTime[] as object as well, but not as object[] because it needs casting/converting for each item in the array. compiler will complain about the latter.

you can write Static Extension/Linq to convert DateTime[] into object[].

when function is expecting object[], it is not expecting array of objects.

when function is expecting object, you can pass DateTime, because DateTime being of type "struct" inherits from object. hope it helps :)